# Best practices when store data

Tags: c#, database

I want to make an application in c# where I can keep all my notes and private howto's.
The GUI looks like this:

```
---------------------------------
| Filter   |     ListView       |
------------                    |
| TreeView |                    |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
|          |                    |
---------------------------------
```

I want all notes to be seen in the ListView and as I type in Filter I want the ListView to remove those notes I'm not interested in. 
TreeView will show all "tags" that Ive added to my notes and by selecting one or multiple it will also filter out the notes I'm interested in.

So I got this class which got the variables `tag` ,which is a string of all keywords Ive entered for this note, and `note`, which is a string with the note itself.

So, how is the best way to do this?
Should I do a sql were I keep all my notes and do a query everytime I want to update the ListView? 
Or should I do some sort of serialization when I close and read it to memory when application is launched and? 
What is the best way to do this and I also want it to perform well even if I get loads of notes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have quite a few options to you here, each one has their strengths and weaknesses.

**1. Flat Files**

You could of course write this information to standard flat files and read them into memory when the application starts, this is simple to read and write however you will need to load them all into memory in order to do sorting and querying of the data. This is not great if you have lots of notes.

**2. Entity Framework**

Entity Framework would be my own personal preference for this as you can query the data as you need it from the database, it would also make features you have mentioned like the tree view alot easier to implement. For this scenario I would probably create a local database (SQLCE) using Code First as this would mean you did not need a full SQL Server Instance for your application.

Another nice feature of Entity Framework is that it will automatically create your database for you if it does not exist as well as allowing you to simply work with C# poco classes that represent records in your database.

**3. NOSQL Databases**

This could be another option for you, there are plenty of NOSQL databases out there which might very well suit your needs, I must admit I have little or no experience with them however they would certainly be up to the job. I will allow someone with more experience with them guide you.